# Is there an opposite of want?

Tags: antonyms, charles-dickens

In Charles Dickens' book "A Christmas Carol", the children of Want and Ignorance crawl out of the Ghost of Christmas Present's robes. My understanding of this kind of "want" is the want of objects for themselves. Is there a single word opposite of "want" (i.e. "wanting to give")?

Comment: "Satiation" is the satisfaction of want.  "Charity" is the act of giving because of a desire to give.

Comment: Maybe **generosity**..?

Comment: *Want* here does not mean *desire* but *neediness, destitution, poverty*.

Comment: Right. And therefore its opposite is _comfort_; i.e, a living wage.

Comment: [Insert "DO NOT WANT" meme here]

Comment: @MasonWheeler Curses, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 32):

You misunderstand *want*, here. The noun is meant.  As [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=want) says:

Noun: want  wónt

1. A state of extreme poverty

   - privation, deprivation, neediness
2. The state of needing something that is absent or unavailable
   "for want of a nail the shoe was lost";

   - lack, deficiency
3. Anything that is necessary but lacking
   "I tried to supply his wants";

   - need
4. A specific feeling of desire

   - wish, wishing

Here, it is all about meaning #1 (or #2 or to some extent #3, but not #4).

And googling for "*want antonym noun*" tells you, among other things:

**Near Antonyms**: abundance, amplitude, bounty, plenitude, plenteousness, plentifulness, plentitude, plenty, wealth; adequacy, sufficiency; excess, overabundance, oversupply, superabundance, surfeit, surplus; deluge, flood; bushel, deal, gobs, heap, loads, lot, mass, mountain, much, oodles, peck, pile, pot, quantity, raft, reams, scads, stack, volume, wad; fund, pool, stock, supply; cache, hoard, stash, stockpile

**Antonyms**: presence

-- [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/want)

Comment: Yes. A Christmas Carol uses "want" in both senses, but there the two key uses of "want" in the opening that help explain the girl's name: 1. "Many thousands are in want of common necessaries; hundreds of thousands are in want of common comforts, sir." 2. "We choose this time, because it is a time, of all others, when Want is keenly felt, and Abundance rejoices." The girl personifies poverty. https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-h/46-h.htm

Comment: Note that Dickens himself suggests a specific single word opposite of Want: Abundance.

Comment: @JeremyDouglass: You can provide it as a separate answer, if you like. (I upvoted the comments.) My answer mentions *abundance*, but the info about Dickens is also useful.

Answer (score 17):

In this context and style, the best word would probably be "plenty". As in "Children of Plenty and Wisdom", or something like that.

Answer (score 10):

Charles Dickens suggests that, in the context of his story, the single word opposite (the antonym) of "Want" is "Abundance."

Two quotations from the opening chapter of [*A Christmas Carol*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-h/46-h.htm) use the word "want" in ways that explain the usage of the girl Want's name. The portly gentlemen use it when they request a donation from Scrooge (*emphasis added*):

1. "Many thousands are in *want* of common necessaries; hundreds of thousands are in *want* of common comforts, sir."
2. "We choose this time, because it is a time, of all others, when ***Want* is keenly felt, and Abundance rejoices.**"

In the first example, being "in want" is being needy / in need, as in poverty.

In the second example the word "Want" is capitalized. This is "allegorical personification": the gentlemen are speaking about poverty as if about a person. This is very uncommon in contemporary English usage, but was more common in Dickens' day. Later Scrooge will meet a little girl named Want who personifies / physically embodies poverty.

Your question was for "a single word opposite of want," and there are *many*, but Dickens suggests Abundance: rather than being "in want," having *much more* than enough.

Answer (score 2):

*The children of **satiety*** (the condition of having any appetite or desire gratified to excess (OED)).